# Limit of infimum sequence of concave functions over convex sets

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, convex-analysis

> Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ be convex, and let $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ be concave. Prove that for every $x \in X$ and every sequence $\{x_n\}$ converging to $x \in X$, we have
> $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} \inf f(x_n) \ge f(x).
> $$

**My attempt at a solution:**

Since we are provided that the function is concave on a convex set, then it follows that the function is continuous. Using the theorem that $f$ is continuous at the point $x$ in $X$ if and only if for all sequences $x_n$ in $X$, if $x_n \to x$ as $n \to \infty$, then $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: But $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ given by $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $0<x<1$ is concave and not continuous.

Answer (score 1):

We can split $(x_n)$ into two sequences one of which stays above $x$ and another  which stays below $x$. It is enough to prove the inequality for each of these subsequences.
Let $x<x_n <x+1$ Then $x_n=t_nx+(1-t_n)(x+1)$ where $t_n=x+1-x_n \to 1$. Note that $0<t_n <1$. Hence $f(x_n)\geq t_nf(x)+(1-t_n) f(x+1)$ and $\lim \inf f(x_n) \geq (1) (f(x))+(0)(f(x+1))=f(x)$.

There is  a similar argument when $x-1 <x_n <x$. Can you write out the proof in this case?